# Return false in JavaScript If statement when value is duplicated

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a JS if statement which gets data every 30 seconds through Ajax. I want my if statement to be in a way that if the variable name with the same value already been processed, it doesn't process it again. For example if var name John already been processed it doesn't process it again.

Does anyone has a solution for this?

```js
ajax_call = function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "test.php",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(response) {

      var len = response.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var name = response[i].name;
        var size = response[i].size;

      }

      var one = "6-8";

      if (size == one && name != name) {
        person.val++;
        person.value = person.val;

      } else {
        console.log("name already exist");
      }
    }
};
var interval = 30000;
setInterval(ajax_call, interval);
});
```

Comment: I have no idea what `size` is supposed to be, but your if condition for `name` solves your problem. Can you explain further what errors you have or what doesn't work with this code?

Comment: You have an extra `});` in your code sample

Comment: `name` and `size` are always going to be the last things in the response.  Not sure why you are looping to get that.

Comment: Important technical note: you're _not_ getting data every 30 seconds. You're getting data _at most_ once every 30 seconds, but timeout/interval _only_ guarantee they won't run faster than the time you give. If your tab is not visible to the user, your intervals become a minute, not 30 seconds, because of timer throttling (and in fact, you should write code to stop the interval entirely on document blur, and then pick it back up on focus).

Comment: Yeah have to agree with Randy, a little bit more context code for the current success response. I cant see what you trying to check is processed. Are you passing any data in your ajax call? Also great point above from @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: @RandyCasburn I am getting a output but this part of program doesn't work : && name != name . basically I want the value of the name to be stored in a variable and compare it with the new name value and if it is duplicate, if statement returns false.

Comment: For your last comment you will need a variable outside of your ajax function scope which you update on success and re-check on the next ajax call. Currently every time your ajax fires those vars in success will just reset with the new response data. You are not storing anything to check on the next ajax response.

Comment: That --------------^

Comment: @joshmoto The problem is that I can't send the value of my local variable (name) to a global variable outside the function. When I define a variable outside function I get : name is not defined error. Do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: @joshmoto ok, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you will need a variable outside of your `$.ajax` function scope which you update on success and re-check on the next `$.ajax` call. Currently every time your `$.ajax` fires those vars in `success:` will just reset with the new `response` data.

In this example I am using `new Set()` object to add/store names and check if name exists so you can do your magic if name does not exist in `let processed = new Set();` storage object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

See my comments in code below (not tested)...

```
// constant variable ajax_call_interval
const ajax_call_interval = 30000;

// updatable variable processed set object for storing processed names
let processed = new Set();

// updatable bool check variable ajax_call_running
let ajax_call_running = false;

// ajax call function
function ajax_call() {

  // update ajax_call_running var to bool true
  ajax_call_running = true;

  // jquery ajax call
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "test.php",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(response) {

      // great success 
      console.log("success");

      // loop through response json as key / data
      $.each(response, function(key, data) {

        // if processed set object has data.name already
        if (processed.has(data.name)) {

          // log name already exists
          console.log("name already exists in processed");

          // this will skip to the next json data item in this jquery each loop

        // else if name does exist in processed set object then...  
        } else {

          // add new name to processed set object var for use in next ajax call
          processed.add(data.name);

          // log name added to processed
          console.log("new name added to processed");

          // do your other magic here for unprocessed name json data
          // ...
          let name = data.name;
          let size = data.size;

        }

      });

      // i am assuming the below should run once the above jquery each function has completed looping through your json response

      // update ajax_call_running var to bool false
      ajax_call_running = false;

      // re-run our ajax call in 30000 ms
      ajax_call_runner(ajax_call_interval);

    },
    error: function(error) {

      // oh no 
      console.log("error");

      // do error response stuff here...

      // update ajax_call_running var to bool false
      ajax_call_running = false;

      // re-run our ajax call in 30000 ms anyway
      ajax_call_runner(ajax_call_interval);

    }

  });

}

// ajax call runner function with interval ms param
function ajax_call_runner(interval) {

  // set time out interval for ajax runner
  setTimeout(function() {

    // if ajax call is not running then
    if (!ajax_call_running) {

      // fire the ajax call
      ajax_call();

    }

  // interval time ms using parent function param
  }, interval);

}

// shorthand for $(document).ready()
$(function() {

  // run our ajax call in 1 ms
  ajax_call_runner(1);

});
```

Comment: Fixed , plus added a `ajax_call_running` just to make sure the `ajax_call_runner` function never runs while a `ajax_call` function is running. Probably overkill but just incase.

Comment: Thanks joshmoto. I will use your code and let you know the outcome.

Comment: No worries, this is not a like for like code fix to your problem, but read my code comments and this may handle your processed name check concept better 

Comment: It worked very well joshmoto. I appreciate your help.

Comment: No worries glad it helped 